# excel multiple sheets data to json data using Javascript and xlsx.js and Display inside <pre> tag

Tags: javascript, html, json, worksheet

Index.php- To upload excel file and display json data inside pre tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Budget</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>    
<body>
<div class="col-sm-6 custom-file"> <!-- 2nd column -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input class="form" type="file" id="fileUpload"> // upload .xlsx, .xls file 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="uploadExcel">Convert</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        <PRE id="jsonData"></PRE> <!-- display Json data of multiple sheets from workbook(budget_book.xls) -->
        </div>
<script src="js/file.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.9/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

file.js for uploading excel files and fetch Multiple excel sheets data and convert to Json

```
let rABS=true;
let input=document.getElementById('fileUpload');
let uploadExcel=document.getElementById('uploadExcel');
let jsonObject=[];

input.addEventListener('change',function(Event){
    selectedFile=Event.target.files[0]; 
}); 

uploadExcel.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(selectedFile){
        console.log(selectedFile);
         var reader = new FileReader();
        
        if(rABS){reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);}
        else{reader.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);}
         
       /*  reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
          document.getElementById('jsonData').innerText = this.result;
        }); */
        reader.onload=(event)=>{
        
            let data=event.target.result;
            let workbook=XLSX.read(data,{type:rABS ?'binary':'array'});
            let sheet_name_list=workbook.SheetNames;
            console.log(sheet_name_list);
            
           
          sheet_name_list.forEach(sheet => {
                let worksheet=workbook.Sheets[sheet];
                console.log(sheet);
                let rowObject=XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(worksheet);
                jsonObject=JSON.stringify(rowObject,undefined,2);
                document.getElementById('jsonData').innerHTML=jsonObject; // display multiple excel sheets data inside <pre> tag in index.php
            });
            
         };
        
    }
});
```

There are two sheets (sheet1 and sheet2) in my budget_book.xlsx but the code only display last sheet(i.e sheet2)

[image: Budget_book.xls with two sheets]

foreach loop is working fine as it shows 2 sheets in console and also data from sheet1 is showing in console log but  shows  data from sheet2 (last sheet) inside .

[image: JSON Data inside pre tag and console]

But inside  tag it doesnot show data from sheet1 of Budget_Book.xls

[image: Budget_Book Sheet1 data converted to Json not showing inside tag]

Kindly provide me solution to this issue to display Json data from both sheets. Is there alternative way to achieve this as this will also be welcomed. Please provide pure javascript solution only.

Comment: just a tip: do `workbook = await selectedFile.arrayBuffer().then(b => XLSX.read(b))`

Comment: @Endless - As it should be use with async function I am unable to get clear view regarding this code. when I use `reader.onload=async(event)=>{ let data=event.target.result; let workbook = await selectedFile.arrayBuffer().then(b => XLSX.read(b)); //let workbook=XLSX.read(data,{type:rABS ?'binary':'array'}); console.log(workbook); It throws the error as below in console. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.replace is not a function     at Object.r [as decode] (xlsx.full.min.js:10)     at async HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (file.js:20)`